# Flutter build is still using an obsolete proxy address

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Once I tried to build using a proxy. Later whenever I try to rebuild the app using no or a different proxy it still wants to connect using the old proxy:

> Connect to **127.0.0.1:9666 [/127.0.0.1]** failed: Connection refused: connect

[image: Error details]
**Notes**:

- I've already cleared Flutter and Android Studio caches
- Flutter packages are working perfectly
- It throws when `gradle` is participating
- Proxy settings in Android Studio is set to auto
- Gradle plugins are updated to the latest version
- My gradle.properties file doesn't contain any proxy related configuration

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the solution:

Since the problem was happening for all of the projects, I would investigate the global gradle settings file named `gradle.properties` located at `USER_HOME/.gradle` directory.

After `commenting`/removing proxy related lines everything fixed:

```
# systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
# systemProp.https.proxyPort=9666
# systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
# systemProp.http.proxyPort=9666
```